# Ionic State.go is not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

THIS IS MY LOGIN CONTROLLER

```
app.controller('lgctrl', function ($scope, $state) {
    $scope.open = function () {
        $state.go('home-menu');
    }
});
```

THIS IS MY App.js

```
 $stateProvider.state('login', {
     url: '/login',
     templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
     controller: 'lgctrl'
 });
 $stateProvider.state('app', {
     url: '/app',
     abstract: true,
     templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
     controller: 'AppCtrl'
 });
 $stateProvider.state('app.home-menu', {
     url: '/home-menu',
     views: {
         'menuContent': {
             templateUrl: "templates/home-menu.html"
         }
     }
 });
```

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

THIS IS MY Login.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Login">
    <ion-content>
        <div class="list">
            <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                <span class="input-label">Email</span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Email">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                <span class="input-label">Password</span>
                <input type="Password" placeholder="Password">
            </label>
        </div>
        <button   ng-click="open()" class="button button-block button-positive">
            Login
        </button >
        Don't have an Account? <a href = "#/signup">Sign-Up</a> | <a href="" >FAQ</a>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

when i am clicking on login button i am getting this error my state.go is not redirecting to the home-menu page

```
Error: Could not resolve 'home-menu' from state 'login'
    at Object.transitionTo (ionic.bundle.js:52013)
    at Object.go (ionic.bundle.js:51946)
    at Scope.$scope.open (Controller.js:38)
    at fn (eval at compile (ionic.bundle.js:27638), <anonymous>:4:203)
    at ionic.bundle.js:65427
    at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:30395)
    at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:30495)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:65426)
    at defaultHandlerWrapper (ionic.bundle.js:16787)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (ionic.bundle.js:16775)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your route config, you've defined your state as 'app.home-menu', but try to access it as 'home-menu' in the controller. As such, ui-router can't find a matching state definition for 'home-menu'

Try `$state.go('app.home-menu');` instead

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: i want to add tabs with this side menu ? what should i do ?

Comment: You should post that as a new question

Answer (score 0):

try updating the below code.

```
   $stateProvider
    .state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
                controller : 'lgctrl'
            });

     .state('app', {
            url: '/app',
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
            controller: 'AppCtrl'
              });

     .state('app.home-menu', {
                url: '/home-menu',
                views: {
                  'menuContent' :{
                    templateUrl: "templates/home-menu.html"
                  }
                }
              });
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
```

Comment: Does it Sound any difference ?

Comment: I have placed $stateProvider many times, try this and tell me what you get. if not then lets think about it

Comment: Actually there will the error u need to remove colons after every state if you are trying to remove state provider from every state...

Comment: no i have not removed from every state i have placed one on the top that reffers to other states